# ADD charging station to OMNeT++ and VEINS

Tags: security, omnet++, veins, sumo, vehicle-routing

I am new in omnet++ and am trying to learn how it works, but I need help now.

I am simulating a part of the city using SUMO- vehicles and charging stations. I learned how to integrate SUMO with onmnet++ with VEINS. Everything is okay, the simulation works, and there is a message exchange between cars and RUS. But I couldn't see the charging stations in the VEINS framework.

For over 10 days, I have been trying online, reading papers and OMNeT++ documents. Also, there is no information on how to make the Charging station I created in SUMO appear in OMNET++ or even create a charging station in OMNET++ itself.

I appreciate any information, references, books or videos you can share.

Thank you

I expect some guidance , information, videos, papers or books.